# Proof of Perron Frobenius Theorem

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values, nonnegative-matrices

I found this [proof](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eknill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture34.pdf) of Perron Frobenius Theorem using Banach Fixed Point Theorem very elegant.

---

[image]

---

However, I can't quite get the claim (in the 6th line from the top on page 2) saying that

> $(A|w|)$ is a vector with length smaller than $\lambda L$, where $L$ is the length of $w$

This claim makes sense to me if $\lambda$ is the maximum singular value but I think $\lambda$ is the maximum eigenvalue. And I think the matrix $A$ can be asymmetric and so the eigenvalues and singular values do not need to be the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added screenshot.

Comment: It seems that your question has also been asked (and answered) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2768002/793015).